# Query to find the last two characters of a column result set

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns SERIAL_NO,BUILD in DETAILSTBL and when i run the below query I get the following result set

```
select SERIAL_NO,BUILD from DETAILSTBL where SERIAL_NO like 'CCB1X1250AD%' and 
BUILD < 'AJ' and BUILD!=''
```

[image]

If I pass SERIAL_NO from JS to backend as CCB1X1250AE, then I should be able to retrieve all the records lesser than CCB1X1250AE i.e. CCB1X1250AD
CCB1X1250AA
CCB1X1250AB
CCB1X1250AC, I tried writing inner query but unable to get the records, appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Could you please be more specific with examples of your sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: For instance,  select SERIAL_NO,BUILD from DETAILSTBL where SERIAL_NO like 'CCB1X1250AD%' and 
BUILD <(select BUILD  where SERIAL_NO<= 'CCB1X1250AC'
 ) and BUILD!='                                                                                            I have to get the serial number (CCB1X1250AA,CCB1X1250AB and CCB1X1250AC) , whats wrong in my query?

Comment: try 'SERIAL NO like 'CCB1X250%' instead?  You have the 'AD' in there which is constraining your SERIAL_NO to always end in 'AD'

Comment: It would be more helpful if you showed the results of 'select * from detailstbl' or 'select top 20 * from detailstbl', by only showing the results of your attempted query it's difficult to understand what your source data really look like.

Comment: From Javascript I am passing SERIAL_NO =CCB1X1250AD, how can I trim the last two characters and get all the SERIAL_NO's (CCB1X1250AA,CCB1X1250AB , CCB1X1250AC, CCB1X1250AD, CCB1X1250AE, CCB1X1250AF) and then based on what I pass, i.e if I pass CCB1X1250AD then I should be able to get the BUILD and serial numbers less than CCB1X1250AD

Comment: We're trying to help, but we're not understanding what you want.   You provided a query, which presumably returns the result set underneath it. You then say that you have some application (writtten in JS) which is passing a serial number in.... in to what? How does that relate to the query you provided? Where is that being threaded in? How does the information you provided (the screenshot of results and the query) relate to the question you're trying to ask?

Comment: You can get the last two characters of a string like this:  SELECT substring(serial_no, len(serial_no) -1, 2) as a from detailstbl

Comment: I want to remove last two characters of a string

Comment: @priya, if you want to find out the string which are less than the string that you have input then use ROW_NUMBER first. sort string according to the SERIAL_NO and BUILD  and then use as a comparison instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you you want this:

```
 select SERIAL_NO,BUILD from DETAILSTBL where SERIAL_NO like 'CCB1X1250A%' and BUILD < 'AJ' and BUILD!='' and SERIAL_NO < 'CCB1X1250AD'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will select all but the last two characters of serial_no:

```
SELECT substring(serial_no, 0, len(serial_no) -1) as a from detailstbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to provide row number to BUILD column according to SERIAL_NO column and then compare with the number column.

```
with TMP_DETAILSTBL
as 
(
    select serial_no, build, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(SERIAL_NO,9) ORDER BY BUILD) ROW_NO from DETAILSTBL
)
select serial_no, build from TMP_DETAILSTBL
where row_no < (select row_no from TMP_DETAILSTBL where build = 'AE')
```

This will give o/p of Serial no which are less that AE.